# How to execute a normal mode command in a vim function?

Tags: function, vim, command

I am writing a vim function to insert some text in a c++ file, please see the following function:

```
function! InsertDebugInfo()                                                                      
     let i = line('.')                                                               
     call append(i+1, '#ifdef DEBUG')                                                
     call append(i+2, 'std::cout << ""  << std::endl;')                              
     call append(i+3, '#endif')                                                      
     call append(i+4, '')                                                            
     call cursor(i+3, 0)                                                             
endfunction
```

In normal mode, I use `==` to re-indent one code line. My question is 
how to call `==` in the above function. Furthermore, how to execute the
command such as `2f"` which move the cursor to the second `"`.

Answer (score 12):

To indent, you can just use

```
normal ==
```

To find also you can use

```
normal 2f"
```

or even shorter

```
norm <whatever you do in normal mode>
```

Now you might be getting what I'm trying to say.
If not, read documentation `:h normal`.

Answer (score 3):

Try this in your function:

```
execute 'normal 2f"'
```