# Taglist does not get updated dynamically

Tags: vim, ctags, cscope

I am a beginner with VIMscript. While coding, I need to update the tags and cscope database so I can jump and search newly added code (functions, macros etc.)

My `.vimrc` file has following code:

```
function UpdateTags()
    silent! execute (":!rm -rf tags cscope.files cscope.out")
    silent! execute (":!ctags -R . *.c *.h *.hpp *.cpp --tag-relative=yes ./ 2>/dev/null")
    silent! execute (":!cscope -b -R") | redraw!
    normal == :cs reset<CR><CR>
    normal == :TlistUpdate<CR>
endfunction

nnoremap <silent> <C-k> :call UpdateTags()<CR>
```

I see that the tags and cscope.out file is updated. However, i am unable to resolve these few things:

- The screen flickers twice (I have put redraw only once in the function)
- The taglist does not get updated. If I execute `:TlistUpdate` command again manually, then I see the new tags.

**Following code is working:**

```
function UpdateTags()
        call system ("rm -rf tags cscope.files cscope.out")
        call system ("ctags -R . *.c *.h *.hpp *.cpp --tag-relative=yes ./ 2>/dev/null")
        call system ("cscope -b -R")
        silent cscope reset
        TlistUpdate
endfunction
```

Comment: What is `normal == :commands` doing? That doesn’t make much sense to me at a glance.

Comment: I followed this link to add normal commands in function:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38364675/how-to-execute-a-normal-mode-command-in-a-vim-function

Comment: That’s specifically for re-indenting. And you dont need normal for colon/Ex commands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### `sytem()`

Swap `execute` with `system`. This has two benefits:

1. The screen doesn't blink and need redrawing, because of how `system` works
2. You should be able to use `silent` instead of `silent!`—the latter hides any errors

### Use Ex (colon) commands as commands

`normal ==` how you pretend the user ran `==` from normal mode. (You can avoid maps using `normal!`.)

To run, e.g., `:cscope reset` or `:TlistUpdate`, you just run them:

```
function! UpdateTags() abort
  " ...
  cscope reset
  TlistUpdate
  " ...
endfunction
```